# Creating a responsive long form submit

Tags: 7, forms

I have a rather long procedure on form submit (need to send several email to different addresses); when the use submits the form, the application seems to hang while it is doing a lot of work. Is there a Drupal way to show a "operation in progress" (better showing an indicator) without using Ajax and/or Ahah?

Comment: this module looks like similar to you query http://drupal.org/project/hide_submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module looks like similar to your query [Hide Submit](http://drupal.org/project/hide_submit)